# Getting the Minimum Value of an Attribute in a NSSet Made from a One-to-Many Relationship in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsset

I have several objects set up in Core Data, one of which is "Deck" and one of which is "Card". "Cards" have several numbered relationships, including "id". "Deck" has a one-to-many relationship with cards.

What's the best way to find the Card in a Deck that has the minimum value to some numbered attribute, such as id?

Clearly I can get the list of cards like this:

```
NSSet *cardList = self.cards;
```

I think I can build an expression to get a minimum like this:

```
NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"id"];
NSExpression *minExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"min:" 
            arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];
```

But I can't quite suss out how to use that expression to extract the card with the minimum value of id (or just the minimum value of id).

Comment: For future reference, I wrote the following two functions based on Barry Wark's advice:

-(NSNumber *)numberForLeast:(NSString *)leastId {

 NSString *keyPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cards.@min.%@",leastId];
 NSNumber *minId = [self valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
  
 return minId;
}

-(NSSet *)cardsForLeast:(NSString *)leastId {
 
 NSString *keyPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cards.@min.%@",leastId];
 NSNumber *minId = [self valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
 
 NSSet *minCards = [self.cards filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id==%@", minId]]; 
 
 return minCards;
}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using Key-Value coding:

```
//assuming Card has an Id property which is a number
NSNumber *minId = [deck valueForKeyPath:@"cards.@min.Id"];

NSSet *minCards = [[deck cards] filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Id==%@", minId]];
```

will give the `NSSet` of Cards whose `Id` property is equal to the minimum in `deck.cards`.

See the Key-Value Programming Guide's description of [Set and Array Operators](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/ArrayOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176) for more info.

Comment: Yes, although I have to look up the exact syntax every time I use it, Key-Value Coding set and array operators make expression some algorithms *very* easy. Ah, the power of a dynamic language.